# How to log and summarize S3 bandwidth by folder?

Tags: amazon-s3

I have an S3 bucket set up with several folders, each one representing a single user. Within each user's folder are several audio files that are streamed to people via HTTP.

I need a way to track bandwidth by folder. I tried enabling S3 logging, but it's not very useful in the format it uses. It spits out tons of small text files with a single line in them, e.g.:

> 61f106674fb0e4a39d49057d70272b980edd365ea3a95e2ae81a2ae83193aea5 xxx [17/Aug/2017:17:39:00 +0000] xxx - xxx REST.GET.OBJECT tracks/user1/xxx.m4a "GET /tracks/user1/xxx.m4a HTTP/1.1" 200 - 4911363 4911363 165 143 "https://xxx" "Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_11_6) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/60.0.3112.101 Safari/537.36" -

I was hoping for a CSV with file sizes and file paths listed out. Is there another way to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, Amazon S3 bucket logging files are the best source of the information you seek. They are small files because they are generated on a regular basis. New files are created each time period, rather than appending to existing files.

An easy way to query their content is to use [Amazon Athena](http://aws.mannem.me/?p=1462), which allows you to write SQL-like queries across data stored in Amazon S3.

See: [Using AWS Athena to query S3 Server Access Logs](http://aws.mannem.me/?p=1462)